# Ruby hash of hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I need to have a hash to collect results, for example:

```
results = Hash.new()

results['127.0.0.1'] = Hash.new()
results['127.0.0.2'] = Hash.new()

results['127.0.0.1']['port'] = '80'
results['127.0.0.2']['port'] = '80'

results['127.0.0.1']['ver'] = 'abc'
results['127.0.0.1']['ver'] = 'def'
```

It seem works fine, but now can I show results? :)
I would like have:

```
ip: 127.0.0.1
port: 80
ver: abc
ip: 127.0.0.2
port: 80
ver: def
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why a hash and not an object?

Answer (score 2):

Better way to define hash:

```
result = {
  '127.0.0.1' => {
    port: 80,
    ver: 'abc'
  },
  '127.0.0.2' => {
    port: 80,
    ver: 'def'
  }
}
```

and then:

```
result.each do |key, value|
  puts "ip: #{key}"
  value.each { |k,v| puts "\t#{key}: #{value}" }
end
```

This method will work also if you add some extra options to hash.

But if you want it only for debugging read about `awesome_print`.

Answer (score 2):

```
results.each do |k, v| 
    puts "IP: #{k}, Port: #{v['port']}, Ver: #{v['ver']}"
end
```